# Почему 2<.. не работает?

Tags: swift, range

```
var dragonCharacteristic = ("зеленый", 2.1)

switch dragonCharacteristic {
case ("зеленый", 0...2):
    print("Поместите дракона в загон 1")
case ("красный", 0...2):
    print("Поместите дракона в загон 2")
case ("красный", 2<..), ("зеленый", 2<..): // ПОЧЕМУ 2<.. НЕ РАБОТАЕТ?
    print("Поместите дракона в загон 3")
default:
    print("Дракон с неизвестными параметрами")
}
```

Почему нельзя задать диапазон 2<.. ? То есть диапазон "более двух" ? Компилятор ругается. Заранее спасибо :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что в Swift нет такого оператора. Совсем недавно, в Swift 4, были представлены `one-sided ranges`:

```
- 0...  
- ...0  
- ..<0
```

По сути своей, это ни что иное как операторы вида:

> postfix operator ...

Создающие соответствующие range: PartialRangeThrough, PartialRangeUpTo, PartialRangeFrom.

Поэтому в данном случае оптимальным по читаемости является Ваш вариант из комментария:

```
case ("зеленый", let weight) where weight > 2:
```

если у Вас weight гарантированно будет больше 0 (а вдруг), то можно заменить конструкцией

```
case ("зеленый", _):
```

Также, при создании собственных операторов нельзя использовать точки, иначе можно было бы написать что-то подходящее. Пример:

```
postfix operator <-- //(представим, что это <..)
extension Double {
    static postfix func <-- (_ lowerBound: Double) -> PartialRangeFrom<Double> {
        return (lowerBound + .leastNormalMagnitude)...
    }
}
```

Тогда можно использовать как Вы хотите:

```
case ("зеленый", 2<--):
```

Но это довольно спорное решение.

Также можно по-другому разбить на группы и использовать доступные операторы:

```
switch dragonCharacteristic {
case (_, ..<0):
    print("Дракон с отрицательной массой? Поместите дракона в Круговерть Пустоты")
case ("зеленый", 0...2):
    print("Поместите дракона в загон 1")
case ("красный", 0...2):
    print("Поместите дракона в загон 2")
case ("красный", _), ("зеленый", _):
    print("Поместите дракона в загон 3")
default:
    print("Дракон с неизвестными параметрами")
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое :) не думал что вначале обучения наткнусь на отсутствующий оператор **2<..** . Но мне почему-то верится, что в следующих версиях его добавят )

Answer (score 0):

Используй просто `2...`,  если нестрогое равенство (2 и более), и `3...`, если тебе нужно получить 3 и более.
Такого `<..` попросту нет в Swift, по неизвестным лично мне причинам

Comment: То есть только обходные пути типа

**case ("зеленый", let weight) where weight > 2:**
?

Comment: да, скорей всего. в swift диапазоны реализованы для меня непонятно, я бы вообще не использовал их.